# Solrj ClientUtils toQueryString escapes facet.pivot field comma

Tags: solr, solrj

The `toQueryString` method inside Solrj's `ClientUtils` class is called when the http request is formed internally. But in this process, it also encodes the commas (,) that need to be sent in the facet.pivot field.

eg . `facet.pivot=A1,A2 gets sent as facet.pivot=A1%2CA2`

Because of this the query returns no result.

Please suggest a mechanism to report this or any work around for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is about escaping/encoding the query for a solr request.

In current version of solr the `toQueryString` method is moved to [SolrParams](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_4_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/common/params/SolrParams.html#toQueryString%28%29). But never the less "%2C" ist correct for "," in utf-8.
So most likely you have a problem on server side with unencoding the params.

Try solr in current version, because in this case you don't need to config the servlet container properly: it is now part of solr.

btw: take a look to sub-facets instead of pivot-faceting: http://yonik.com/solr-subfacets/